# How can I filter the Values(As character variable) in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a column as

[image]

When I doing the filtering Value < 50000, it still includes some values which are greater than 50,000.

```
Tree_all_exclusive<-Tree_all %>%
  filter(Value <50000.00)
 

Tree_all_exclusive
```

[image]

Would you please help me to sort this out?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try `filter(as.numeric(Value) < 50000)`

Comment: Why is this a character variable and not a numeric variable? "Not recorded" should be enocoded as (numerical) `NA` values.

Comment: The type of `Value` is "chr" (character) and not numeric (as indicated by "<chr>" in the output). Also, please don't post images of code or data....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are dealing with a character variable. Try to run `as.numeric()` on the Value column first.